# Android Sliding Menu show

Tags: android, android-sliding

I work with [jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) Library, i followed all the instructions, but when I try sliding the menu is not seen, how to show it?

**My Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
        menu.setSlidingEnabled(true);
        menu.showContent();

    }
  }
```

in `menu_frame` layout i have `FrameLayout` and one `TextView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this after your setContentView

```
setBehindContentView(R.layout.name_of_your_menu_layout);
```

See if it helps!

Comment: I can't it add in android.app.Activity!

Comment: I see, perhaps extending SlidingActivity instead of Activity will let you add it

Comment: WoW, it's Work Thank's Big Thank's!

Comment: Glad it helps! I'm also trying to learn how this library works and so far it's not easy!

Comment: Can you help else, how to my menu layout with ListView, add adapter

Comment: Perhaps my code here can help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162683/behind-offset-not-working-when-using-slidingmenu

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code Which worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenumain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and in your main activity add the above sliding menu file...

Comment: how to add this file, could u plz elaborate!

Comment: @rawD3buGGG3R create an activity and import it !!