# SlidingMenu not showing properly

Tags: android, android-sliding

I'm a Beginner Android Programmer and I'm toying around with [JFeinstein's awesome sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), trying to figure out how it works and implement it in my apps but in all of my implementations the behind view covers 100% of the above view.

Also, the only way to go back to the above view is to press the back button, so no `"sliding"` back either. If I understand correctly, this should be controlled by the `BehindViewOffset`, yet I don't seem to be getting it to work. Anyway, here's a little sample code:

Here's my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setBehindContentView(R.layout.testing);

        populate();

        SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
        menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);
        menu.setMenu(R.layout.testing);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            toggle();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void populate() {

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] values = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
                "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

And the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sadly I can't post a screenshot until I earn more rep!

**Edit:** Added the dimen.xml

```
    <resources>
    <dimen name="slidingmenu_offset">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="list_padding">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="shadow_width">15dp</dimen>
    <integer name="num_cols">1</integer>
</resources>
```

Comment: Have you properly added `example/res/values/dimen.xml` ? `R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset.`is properly mentioned na?

Comment: Yes, but just in case I've added it to the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so I took a close look at the example and finnaly got it working by changing

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
```

for:

```
SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();
```

So here is the final code for the main activity´s onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setBehindContentView(R.layout.testing);

    populate();

    SlidingMenu menu = getSlidingMenu();

    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    setSlidingActionBarEnabled(true);


}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I was facing the same problem and your solution was what fixed it for me too!